# Retrieving PFUser info other than username, password, objected, etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I added several other columns to my Parse user database. When I want to retrieve a current user's email, I know to type [PFUser currentUser].email. However, let's say I add a "RoomNumber" column; how do I retrieve its value?

I've tried:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] valueForKey: @"RoomNumber"]
```

and

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey: @"RoomNumber"]
```

but both return null. How do I solve this?

Comment: You are of course absolutely sure there is a value in RoomNumber for the current user, and that RoomNumber is spelled exactly so?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey: @"RoomNumber"];
```

should work, or you can use

```
[PFUser currentUser][@"RoomNumber"];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @picciano My critique and request IS in a comment below their post. Check again :-)